# Env vars in Svelte - __myapp is not defined

Tags: javascript, environment-variables, svelte

I'm trying to set up env vars on my Svelte app to hide an API key.

I followed the instructions in this article [https://medium.com/dev-cafe/how-to-setup-env-variables-to-your-svelte-js-app-c1579430f032].

Here's the structure of my rollup.config.js

```
import { config as configDotenv } from 'dotenv';
import replace from '@rollup/plugin-replace';

configDotenv();

export default {
...
plugins: [
    replace({
        __myapp: JSON.stringify({
          env: {
            isProd: production,
            amplitude_api_key : process.env.amplitude_api_key
          } 
        })
      }),
]}
```

When I try to access the env var by calling: `__myapp.env.API_KEY`

I get this error: `__myapp is not defined`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the nesting is the problem.  I was able to get it work using this syntax:

```
replace({
  'process.env.isProd': production,
  'process.env.amplitude_api_key': process.env.amplitude_api_key
}),
```

and then use `process.env.isProd` in your app.  Of course, if you like the `__myapp` thing, you could use `__myapp` instead of `process` on the left side of the replace function in your rollup config.

Answer (score 0):

Even though this thread is solved, I want to point out that your remark **"to hide an API key" is invalid** because .env on clientside is **always parsing** right into your sourcecode. So in other words: your api-key is being parsed (and exposed) in the source once you build.

Answer (score 0):

Because I struggled a lot to import Env in svelte front and none of the answer I found worked out of the box I would like to add my insight to anyone blocked on this topic later on.

Here are the step by step guide that should make it work:

#### Step by Step

1. Install dependencies with `npm install @rollup/plugin-replace dotenv --save-dev`
2. in `rollup.config.js` Add the proper imports:

   ```js
   import { config } from 'dotenv';
   import replace from '@rollup/plugin-replace';
   ```

   and in the `plugins` section, below `export default {` add the following lines:

   ```js
       replace({
           "process.env.config": JSON.stringify(config().parsed)
       }),
   ```
3. Make sure the file `.env` is at the root of your Svelte project
4. (Re)start your app with `npm run dev` (or whatever you are using)
5. In your app, you can access your `.env` variables via: `process.env.config.VARIABLE_NAME` :

   ```js
   console.log(process.env.config)
   /* Output on client:
   **  $> { PUBLIC_API_KEY: 'WW91IHRob3VnaHQgSSB3YXMgc3R1cGlkIG9yIHdoYXQgPw==' }
   */
   ```

---

#### Debugging

If you still get errors, try replacing the lines in the `rollup.config.js` with the following line, and make sure to look at the server console during compilation. That should display the .env content, but you may find an error that was not visible before.

```js
replace({
    "log": console.log(config()) && true,
}),
```

#### Disclaimer

Be aware that with that method any variable you set up in the `.env` will be readable somehow by anyone using the application (via the debug tools for instance). So, do not store any critical secrets for your application. One thing that you can store is api key for any free/open API for instance.

I hope that helps you guys.